# Regular Expression to match pairs of forward slashes, but not escaped or between subsequent http://

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression that can match paired forward slashes (e.g. `/something/`), but skip escaped pairs (e.g. `\/something\/`) and also skip something like subsequent URL's (e.g. `http://something.com and stuff http://somethingelse.org`).

So, in the following example, only the text "jumped over" would be matched, nothing else would be a match:

```
The quick brown fox /jumped over/ the lazy dogs. He was looking for a 
\/website\/ to help him find ways around the dogs because he was sick of 
\/jumping\/ over them. Unfortunately, both http://routesaroundlazydogs.com/ and 
https://maps.lazydogs.com/stuff/things/findmap.aspx were both down on the day he 
was looking.
```

The regex has to work in Javascript (i.e. no look-behinds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  (^|\s+)/([A-Z0-9a-z ]+)/\s+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zkMBAgw6uKSuvXyj)

Comment: `/foo\/bar/` should probably match, if the intent of escaping the middle `/` is to treat it as normal text.

Comment: The capture I _want_ can appear at the beginning of the string, so this almost works, but not quite.

Comment: @RobertC.Barth I change it to make sure it counts start of strings also :D

Comment: @Douglas if you make this edit it should work `[A-Z0-9a-z ]` -> `[A-Z0-9a-z \\/]`

Comment: As far as I can tell, this works for my scenario, so I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer. Two things: The forward slashes need to be escaped in the regex (e.g. `\/`), and also I modified the end similar to the beginning, with the addition of being able to match at the end of a sentence, in addition to the end the text (`(^|\s+)\/([A-Z0-9a-z ]+)\/(\s+|$|\.)`).

Comment: [It doesn't work and misses `/second/`](http://regex101.com/r/bE5jZ5/4) in the linked demo.

Answer (score 1):

How about using this regex:

```
\\\/.*?\\\/|\/\/\S*|\/(.*?[^\\])\/
```

And use matched group #1 for your match.

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bE5jZ5/3)

Comment: `/jumped/ /over/` should probably match twice, `jumped` and `over`, not the whole `jumped/ /over` string.

Comment: This matches every occurrence of forward slash pairs, which is incorrect. Please re-read the question.

Comment: @RobertC.Barth: I have read your question. But you probably didn't read this line in my answer: `And use matched group #1 for your match.` In the demo link I provided look at bottom-right section for your matches.

Comment: Nice. Should `/jumped\/over/` match `jumped\/over` or just `jumped\ `?

Comment: That is a question for OP and I can tell you that without lookbehind not that easy to handle in pure regex solution.

Comment: @Douglas: I made another update to take care of cases like `/jumped\/over/`

Comment: `/jumped\/over/` is not a valid use case. We're searching for pairs, so the pairs have to be escaped. `/jumped over/` should return `"jumped over"` as the match.

Comment: ok great in that case above regex or even `\\\/.*?\\\/|\/\/\S*|\/(.+?)\/` should work.

Comment: I see, this is clever, but I am using the regex in a replace, so it won't work because it matches on all of the forward slashes, as I mentioned. You'll notice in my question I mentioned matching on the specified pair, but nothing else.

Comment: But I wonder how accepted solution can work for you? [See this demo](http://regex101.com/r/bE5jZ5/4) It doesn't match `/second/` from input data. **Also this regex will work very well with `String#replace` method. I can provide you working code if you want.**

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, since you probably want `foo /bar/ foo /bar/ foo` to not match `/ foo /`.

I'd suggest finding a url regex, then doing `input.replace(urlRegex, "")`, then writing a simple parser to read in the `/` pairs instead of a regex.

Comment: This is all part of a larger text parsing routine, which contains a regex for the URL's, so yeah, I guess I could replace the URL's with a sentinel, do the requested matching/replacement, and then replace the sentinels withe the proper links, but I'm hoping to avoid that. And yes, you are correct, your example should match the two `bar`'s, not the `/ foo /`.

Comment: @RobertC.Barth What do you want to do about `/ http://www.example.com/bogus/omg/ /`?